# Add attribute to result of xsl:apply-imports

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XSL stylesheet (A) that imports another one (B). A overrides a template (t) in B, and invokes B's template with apply-imports:

From A:

```
<xsl:template match="t">
    <xsl:apply-imports/>
</xsl:template>
```

From B:

```
<xsl:template match="t">
    <p><!-- Do something --></p>
</xsl:template>
```

I now want A to add an attribute to the fragment (`<p>`...`</p>`) returned by apply-imports. The attribute should be added to element p directly, p should not be wrapped in another element. How can I do this?

Regards,
Jochen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, you can't.

B is self-contained, when its matching template finishes running then `<p>` is already constructed in the result tree and inaccessible to A.

Answer (score 0):

Think about doing some preprocessing to B. It's only a xml after all.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a parameter to your B template and include it in the A match? That way you can add the attribute you want based controlled by the A match.

Comment: Not in this case since I can only change A, not B.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT1, you can achieve the desired result by using a variable to capture the original template output, then modify it afterward. Unfortunately, that requires the `exsl:node-set` external function to convert from the [result tree fragment](https://www.oxygenxml.com/archives/xsl-list/200304/msg01255.html) to a node set.

<sub>(tested with xsltproc)</sub>

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="exsl"
                ...
                version='1.0'>

<xsl:import href="B.xsl" />

<xsl:template match="t">
  <!-- capture inherited template result -->
  <xsl:variable name="baseresult">
    <xsl:apply-imports/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <!-- apply custom transformation each node of the result -->
  <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($baseresult)/node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="class">overrided</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```